# Calculate the area between the two curves $y=3x^2+x-8$ and $y=2x^2+3x$

Tags: integration

I'm having trouble solving this question. I know how to calculate the area between the curves but I'm unsure how to get the upper and lower limits.

Comment: Where do the curves intersect?

Comment: Have you made an Image?

Comment: The limits will be the points where the two curves intersect.  Set $y = y$ and solve for $x.$

Comment: They intersect at (-2,2) and (4,44)

Comment: So my upper limit is 4 and lower -2?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Should i post the result for you, for your Control?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes please if you don't mind.

Comment: Hello Caroline, i have written the result in my post already.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: you can calculate the area as $$\int_{-2}^{4}(2x^2+3x-(3x^2+x-8))x$$ The result should be $36$